# Resize Bitmap image?

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to change the image size when changing screen orientation. I tried to use the following code, but it does not work.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            myImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pic));
            Display d = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();

            int ScreenHeight = d.getHeight();
            int ScreenWidth = d.getWidth();

            Bitmap ScaledImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage , ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 
                             true);

            imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(ScaledImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code to rotate or re size your image in android

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.android);

        int width = bitmapOrg.width();
        int height = bitmapOrg.height();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // rotate the Bitmap
        matrix.postRotate(45);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                          width, height, matrix, true);

        // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
        // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

        // set the Drawable on the ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        // center the Image
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

        // add ImageView to the Layout
        linLayout.addView(imageView,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
                )
        );

        // set LinearLayout as ContentView
        setContentView(linLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Arslan thanks for your help,actually i already added this line in my menifest, but its not working. In portrait mode its working, problem is only with landscape mode. Any other suggestion.